# plotting the lagrangian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, calculus-of-variations

From the differential equation $$\frac{\partial P}{\partial r} = \left[1+\frac{r}{\ln(1+r)}\right]D$$

I get the second-order equation

$$\frac{1}{D}{P(r)}=\text{Ei}\left(2\ln(r+1)) - \text{Ei}(\ln(r+1)\right) + c_{2}r + c_{1}$$

and the following Lagrangian

$$L(P',P,r) = \frac{1}{2}\left(P'^2+2P\left(\frac{-r}{(r+1)\ln^2(r+1)}+\frac{r}{(r+1)\ln(r+1)}+\frac{1}{(r+1)\ln(r+1)}\right)\right).$$

I would like to see the stable (and unstable) points by plotting the Euler-Lagrange solutions with a contour or density plot. Can someone give me advice - preferably in Mathematica or R - on how to do this?

Thanks.
SH

Comment: Could you clarify how you want to "visualize" your Lagrangian? It's a function of functions. Perhaps you want to visualize it for the $P(r)$ which solves the Euler Lagrange equations?

Comment: Yes, to visualize the stable (and unstable) points in a contour or density plot.